# Como navego los valores de posición en un doble puntero?

Tags: c++, array, punteros

Digamos por ejemplo que tengo este código en Dev c++

```
X[nRow-1] = Y[nRow-1] / U[nRow-1][nRow-1];
```

pero yo necesito operar a U [nRow][nRow] como **matrizU entonces como quedaría el código de esa operación?

```
int j = nRow - 1;
int i = nRow - 1;
    
X[nRow-1] = Y[nRow-1] / *(*(matrizU+i)+j);
```

O simplemente

```
X[nRow-1] = Y[nRow-1] / *(*(matrizU+i-1)+j-1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero que nada DevC++ es el editor de código, no el lenguaje de programación.

Al declarar un arreglo tú estás reservando n espacios de memoria contiguos y guardando el puntero de la posición 0. Los corchetes son un *short cut* para la operación de punteros, tú puedes hacerlo de la misma forma. Ambas expresiones son equivalentes:

```
matrix[i] = *(matrix + i)
```

```
matrix[i][j] = *(*(matrix + i) + j)
```